# Feed me less to use me more

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> One half is a little less than kind
>   The other is likely to ease your mind

Hint:

> I’m a 6-letter noun

Comment: Got to be honest, bud - this looks like the minimum amount of effort for a riddle... And I'm anticipating it could be too broad with so little information...

Comment: I believed that the information provided should be precise enough. Nevertheless, @Stiv, in light of your suggestion I’ve added a decisive hint to further restrict possibilities.

Comment: Okay, that now feels more likely to guide an answerer as to whether their ideas are correct. Thanks :)

Comment: (Riddles are often seen as easy low-effort fodder for any Tom, Dick or Harry to have a bash at with the first idea that comes into their head, regardless as to whether their answer matches all of your carefully laid hints. When there are only 3 hints (2 lines and the title) the odds are that you'll get a lot of spurious suggestions or accidental matches that you hadn't planned for. For the integrity of your question - and your own reputation as a setter - you want to minimise that possibility. Anyway, this advice is meant well - keep going, keep developing, and keep the rest of us thinking!)

Comment: I mostly prefer to keep things concise yet precise, but I’ll keep your thought in mind too. Thanks a lot, @Stiv :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the answer is

> napkin

because

> a nap (short sleep) may ease your mind, and "a little less than kind" presumably refers to "A little more than kin, and less than kind" from Hamlet. Not sure about "Feed me less to use me more" but maybe it's something to do with a napkin being able to be used more if less food is deposited onto it.